Trying to fit Qt moc generation with a waf unity build
I'm building a project using waf that generates .moc files for use in Qt. waf's qt5 feature works great at detecting and generating them!
But as soon as I try to use a unity build, the moc runner isn't triggered. I think that the problem is that the unity feature doesn't know to trigger the qt5 feature on the unity file.
My features list is:
"qt5 unity cxx cxxshlib"

Nevermind, this was actually a typo in waf implementation. It was fixed in waf here: https://gitlab.com/ita1024/waf/-/merge_requests/2384
